# Multiple subjects and one pronoun

Tags: pronouns

Consider the following sentence.

> Sheena and Shania went to her home.

Both, Sheena and Shania, are females. To whom the pronoun 'her' refers.

Comment: If something is ambiguous even with context, it is pretty difficult to tell without asking the author. If you are the author, then you should rewrite the sentence.

Comment: It refers to both(Sheena and Shania).

Comment: @Sam How do you know? What if they don't live together? It could also mean they went to the home of a third female

Answer (score 1):

Only context could tell you for certain. It could refer to Sheena, to Shania, or to a third person.

But the last option is the best guess if there's no context, because usually if it were one of the two mentioned, we would repeat that person's name.

> Sheena and Shania went to Sheena's house, where they discussed their unsettlingly similar names.

It would take a lot of weight on one person in the narrative for us to assume that "her" could have a default value of Sheena or Shania such that the clarification is unnecessary.